# Athena View - Need to get a specific value from a column's original value

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I am creating a view in athena from athena table where I need to get a substring from a column value.
I have a column where values are like below:

|12 MO ABC **14.99APR**/1.20PMT|

|36 MO ABC **14.99%APR**/1.20%PMT|

|36 MO ABC **14.99% APR**/1.20%|

|14 MONTH ABC**9.99%APR**/8.79%|

|14 MONTH ABC DEF **9.10% APR**|

From these values I need to get only highlighted APR value.
How can we get it?

Comment: Are you saying that the table appears as a **single column** with ALL of the text you have shown? Is it true that there are sometimes spaces before `APR` and sometimes there are not? Does the first line really not have a `%` character?

Comment: Hello.. 
actually table has more columns but I need to use this column..
Yes, there are spaces sometimes before APR 
and yes first line doesnt have a % character..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT regexp_extract('|36 MO ABC **14.99% APR**/1.20%PMT|', '[\d.%]+ APR')
```

It will return:

```
14.99% APR
```

If the space before `APR` is sometimes missing, you can use:

```
SELECT regexp_extract('|14 MONTH ABC9.99%APR/8.79%|', '[\d.%]+ ?APR')
```